# Amazon BTG refinements for SoftwareVideoGamesGenre

Tags: c#, xml, amazon-web-services, xsd

While trying to list products on Amazon I have come up against so many major issues I'm going crazy working round them. The newest in the list is mapping classifications to products using the XML/XSD C# way.

As noted in a different question [Found Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444338/mapping-amazon-product-category-to-the-correct-category-xsd) there is no direct mapping between them. This is complicated by the fact that Amazons XSD validation requires certain parameters to be required such as SoftwareVideoGamesGenre in the case of Software Video Games which in the UK can be found in the PC & Video Games classification.

My issue is this:

After a search on the www I came across this post [Amazon Software and Video Games Genre](http://ssc.channeladvisor.com/forums/sales-channels/marketplaces/amazon-software-and-video-games-genre) Here it is stated that the refinements (accepted genre types) can be found in the BTG guides. However they are not found in the UK BTG.

My question is:

Has anyone been able to successfully map Amazon classifications to Products as at present I am only able to map to a generalized upper classification without having to manually go through the 10's of thousands of classifications checking each of the required parameters for each product type or to at least a parent more generalized classification using a more generalized product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so here's the best answer for this question.

Each top classification has a subset of product types. each product type has a subset of attributes that are acceptable to Amazon. Certain attributes are required by Amazon, some are optional and some are preferred but not required. It is up to the developer to decide which of the preferred and optional attributes they would like to include in a product feed.

What I had to do to map a classification to a product was to write a class library that contains these sets and subsets. Create a database of the classifications and mappings such that musical Instruments would map to a name I can search for such as musicalInstruments which is mapped to the browse node_Id and a table row Id. Using these details and the product type I was able to generate a matching product which I am able to list on Amazon perfectly.

The only issue I can see is that you will have to develop your class library to cope with each type of product in the top classification. IE Toys & Games would require you to deal with a ToysAndGames product object which is a product of type ToysProductType which is an ItemType Toys. The ToysProductType requires a AgeRecommendation which you will have to supply in order to list the product on Amazon.

You will have to create your class library in such a way as to be able to build you products with the way described above. If you have any questions let me know and I'll be happy to help out.