# Browse all categories in Amazon Marketplace with API call

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am creating an application for those who sell products in Amazon Seller Central. User will create a listing in my web app and list item in Amazon with their seller account.

To do this, I am developing a listing page, where I have to first show all categories. And show them like nodes / trees like how it appears in Amazon when adding a product.

Which API call can help me with obtaining a list of available categories?

Comment: I do not believe Amazon offers an API that will list every available category.  But you can get XSD's of all categories in the following document.  Maybe that will help.  https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/rainier/help/XML_Documentation_Intl._V324496426_.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Is there any api where I can find objects to list items in amazon sellercentral?

No. Unfortunately, all we've got to work with are Browser Tree Guides (BTG), XSDs and a broken link between them:

- The BTGs available in Seller Central are in a format intended to be read by humans - you might be able to parse those Excel files somewhat. There also is no good way to automatically fetch updated BTGs.
- There is no good source for a complete and updates set of XSDs, I had to manually "stitch together" the ones I've got to make them even validate a single product feed. The "Selling on Amazon Guide to XML" is a good start, but unfortunately incomplete.
- There is no good way to find the correct XML format for any given category in the BTG - see more here: [Mapping amazon product category to the correct category XSD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444338/mapping-amazon-product-category-to-the-correct-category-xsd)

If you plan to provide a somewhat integrated solution for third parties, expect this chain to break. A lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the [Browse Tree Report](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/Reports_ReportType.html) from a report through the MWS API. The report type is `_GET_XML_BROWSE_TREE_DATA_`